# Cucumber Java - No features found at file <location>

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber

I am getting the following error while running the maven command "mvn clean verify". I have placed the "feature" file at "C:/Users/304090/eclipse-workspace/evms-qa-testautomation/src/test/resources/". However, its unable to identify the file. Please suggest.

```
Apr 21, 2020 7:19:43 PM io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier get
WARNING: No features found at file:/C:/Users/304090/eclipse-workspace/evms-qa-testautomation/src/test/resources/


0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m
0.000s
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check your test runner class where you have provided path to featch your feature files.currently its looking for `C:/Users/304090/eclipse-workspace/evms-qa-testautomation/src/test/resources/` folder for a .feature files.

`cucumber.api.CucumberOptions` imports the `@CucumberOptions` annotation and it wwll tell where to look for feature files

You need to create features folder into the `src/test/resources` and past your `.feature file` in it. After that just update your runner class

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
     features = "src/test/resources/features/featurefileanme.feature",
     glue={"path of glue package"}
 )

public class TestRunner {
 }
```

with serenity:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/CreatePreVioltReport.feature",
        glue = "stepsDef"
)

public class RunTests {}
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak. My TestRunner is as given below. I am importing @CucumberOptions from io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions.  ' package com.cog.ltaevms.testrunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  plugin = {"pretty"},
  features = "src/test/resources/CreatePreVioltReport.Feature",
  glue = "/src/test/java/com/cog/ltaevms/testrunner")

public class TestRunner {

} '

Comment: check updated solution not sure why your glue codde referring to src/test/java/com/cog/ltaevms/testrunner